# Solaris - permanently update PATH for all users

Tags: solaris, path

I have installed JDK and Groovy on my Solaris 11 machine. I would now like to set things up so that the PATH variable would contain the bin directories whenever I open a shell.

It is my understanding that the following lines added at the end of the `/etc/profile` file should do the trick.

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/jdk/instances/jdk1.7.0
PATH=${PATH}:${JAVA_HOME}/bin

GROOVY_HOME=/usr/local/bin/groovy-2.1.3
PATH=${PATH}:${GROOVY_HOME}/bin

export PATH
```

However, when I restart my putty session, only the JAVA_HOME and GROOVY_HOME variables are affected. The PATH variable stays the same, e.g.

```
/usr/bin:/usr/sbin
```

I am wondering if there is another script that runs after /etc/profile, that might override the PATH variable. But I have no idea where to look.

Or is there another problem?

---

As porposed in a comment, I tried to use the following lines instead, but unfortunatelly with the same effect.

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/jdk/instances/jdk1.7.0
GROOVY_HOME=/usr/local/bin/groovy-2.1.3
export PATH=${PATH}:${GROOVY_HOME}/bin:${JAVA_HOME}/bin
```

Comment: what happens if you set the `JAVA_HOME` and `GROOVY_HOME` variables, then set the path all at once with this: `export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME:$GROOVY_HOME`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check `/etc/default/login` for login shells.  You can force an initial path there.

Adding your variables to /etc/profile should work, depending on the version of Solaris running.  A more portable, for Solaris, way of doing it would be to separate setting the PATH variable and exporting it.

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/jdk/instances/jdk1.7.0
GROOVY_HOME=/usr/local/bin/groovy-2.1.3
PATH=${PATH}:${GROOVY_HOME}/bin:${JAVA_HOME}/bin
export PATH
```

Solaris 11, where `bash` is the default shell will work ok with your profile, but older Solaris version may not parse the `export PATH=...` syntax as expected, or at all.

Also, keep in mind that you're only changing the initial PATH for users.  `/etc/profile` is read before a user's `.profile` is read.

By default, Solaris users will usually end up with their own `.profile` file that contains a default PATH.

```
solaris:~$ grep PATH .*
.profile:export PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/sbin
```

Since this .profile is being read in ***after*** the `/etc/profile` that you've modified, your changes to `$PATH` will be discarded and the user's entries will take over.

You can add these changes for new users by editing the file `/etc/skel/.profile`, but to make the changes permanent for existing users, you would need to edit their individual .profiles, or overwrite them if they haven't edited them themselves.